# Unit ball in the trace class

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $B_1$ be the space of trace class operators in $B(H)$ equipped with the $|| \cdot ||_1$ norm.

Is the unit ball in $B_1$ compact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in its norm topology. No infinite-dimensional locally convex vector space is locally compact. However, the trace-class operators can naturally be viewed as the Banach dual of the compact operators, and with the relative weak-star topology coming from this pairing, the unit ball is compact.

Comment: I know the question has been closed, but I could not quite follow the part about the relative weak-star topology. Sorry, but could you add more details?

Comment: Let $\mathcal K(H)$ denote the compact operators on an infinite-dimensional, separable Hilbert space $H$. It is closed in the operator norm, and therefore a Banach space in its own right. The Banach dual of $\mathcal K(H)$, $\mathcal K^*$, can be identified with the trace-class operators with the trace norm. This is via the following map: if $A$ is a trace-class operator, then the map $T\mapsto \text{tr}(TA)$ is a linear functional on $\mathcal K(H)$, and all continuous linear functionals are of this form. Moreover, this is an isometric map. The Banach-Alaoglu theorem states that any Banach 1/

Comment: dual space, $X^*$, has compact unit ball in the weak-star topology. That is, if we give $X^*$ the topology where a net $\phi_i$ of functionals converges to a functional $\phi$ if and only if for every $x\in X$, $|\phi_i(x)-\phi(x)|\to 0$, the unit ball of $X^*$ is compact.